# Animate CSS Gradient in Bootstrap nav

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions, css-animations

I am working with bootstrap atm and notice my simple css nav button transition wasn't working.

I put this down to bootstrap but then removed my gradient background and just had a solid background color and it worked.

Does a spec for CSS gradient transitions, does this exist? Is there any way I can do this? If not, what is the best solution?.

Below is my fiddle of with the gradient being the orange hover.

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/10245/

The gradient is as follows, so it works somewhat in multiple browsers.

```
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(rgba(254, 204, 177, 1)), color-stop(0.5, rgba(241, 116, 50, 1)), color-stop(0.51, rgba(234, 85, 7, 1)), to(rgba(251, 149, 94, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(254, 204, 177, 1) 0%, rgba(241, 116, 50, 1) 50%, rgba(234, 85, 7, 1) 51%, rgba(251, 149, 94, 1) 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(254, 204, 177, 1) 0%, rgba(241, 116, 50, 1) 50%, rgba(234, 85, 7, 1) 51%, rgba(251, 149, 94, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(254, 204, 177, 1) 0%, rgba(241, 116, 50, 1) 50%, rgba(234, 85, 7, 1) 51%, rgba(251, 149, 94, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(254, 204, 177, 1) 0%, rgba(241, 116, 50, 1) 50%, rgba(234, 85, 7, 1) 51%, rgba(251, 149, 94, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#feccb1', endColorstr='#fb955e', GradientType=0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) fails where a solid color works is because `linear-gradient` actually creates an image. The longhand property it corresponds to is `background-image`, not `background-color`.

A `background-image` is not transitional, however using positioning and a pseudo-element, we can use the `opacity` property to emulate it. Here is a simple example that shows off this technique.

## Example:

```css
li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    font-size: 40px;
    /*Must have positioning.*/
    position: relative;
}
li a {
    color: white;
    /*Must have positoning.*/
    position: relative;
}
li:before {
    /*Make it fill the container.*/
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    /*Create gradient.*/
    background: rgb(254, 204, 177);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(rgba(254, 204, 177, 1)), color-stop(0.5, rgba(241, 116, 50, 1)), color-stop(0.51, rgba(234, 85, 7, 1)), to(rgba(251, 149, 94, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(254, 204, 177, 1) 0%, rgba(241, 116, 50, 1) 50%, rgba(234, 85, 7, 1) 51%, rgba(251, 149, 94, 1) 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(254, 204, 177, 1) 0%, rgba(241, 116, 50, 1) 50%, rgba(234, 85, 7, 1) 51%, rgba(251, 149, 94, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(254, 204, 177, 1) 0%, rgba(241, 116, 50, 1) 50%, rgba(234, 85, 7, 1) 51%, rgba(251, 149, 94, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(254, 204, 177, 1) 0%, rgba(241, 116, 50, 1) 50%, rgba(234, 85, 7, 1) 51%, rgba(251, 149, 94, 1) 100%);
    /*Transition the opacity.*/
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

li:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<li>
    <a href="#">test</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation as well as the solution.  I was finding it difficult to wrap my head why it could animate a gradient.  Cheers!